# Travis CI not recognizing large resolution on xvfb causing feature specs to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, travis-ci, xvfb

I am trying to get travis to pass my feature specs, however with xvfb default settings, it runs with a smaller window. As the site uses responsive webdesign, it means it's viewing the page as if it were on mobile. My tests fail because of this.

I searched around and found various different ways to set up my `.travis.yml` file, none of which work, but here is what I currently have:

**.travis.yml**

```
language: ruby
rvm:
- 2.3.0
addons:
  postgresql: "9.4"

before_install:
  - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
  - "/sbin/start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /tmp/custom_xvfb_99.pid --make-pidfile --background --exec /usr/bin/Xvfb -- :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x16"
  - "sleep 3"

before_script:
- cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml
- cp config/application.yml.example config/application.yml
- psql -c 'create database db_test;' -U postgres

script:
- bundle exec rake db:migrate
- bundle exec rake
```

Sample view code that has the responsive bit (in haml):

**_view.haml**

```
.row
  .col-xs-12
    %label
      %span.visible-lg-inline Line {{question + 1}}:
      %b
```

As you can see, the `visible-lg` thing is what is borking things. The entire app uses `visible-lg`/`hidden-lg` classes in different spots so changing this isn't an option. Also it's bootstrapped.

Associated Travis error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content("Line 1: #{question}")
```

My specs pass locally, since Firefox loads up a standard sized window vs mobile-sized/small window.  How do I change my `.travis.yml` file to get it to respect the larger screen resolution I've set?

Another example Travis error:

```
Failure/Error: click_on 'Preview'

 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find link or button "Preview"
```

('Preview' exists but not in mobile mode)

I am using Ruby 2.3, Rails 4.2.5, and AngularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was not my travis.yml file as I originally thought.

After a week of searching, I stumbled upon this: 
https://discuss.circleci.com/t/capybara-driver-rack-test/407  which had a link to this: http://blaulabs.de/2011/11/22/acceptance-testing-with-responsive-layouts/

In my `spec/spec_helper.rb` I put the following at the very bottom after the config section(s):

```
def set_selenium_window_size_to_large
  page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1280, 1280)
end

def set_selenium_window_size_to_small
  page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(600, 600)
end
```

With the above code, I can now invoke 2 different window sizes so I can test whether the hamburgler menu options are not displayed when in mobile mode or when in desktop mode.

In my feature specs, I then called that method in my before block so all my tests that needed it get it.  Also, `rails_helper` calls `spec_helper` so I'm covered that way.

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'A question page', :devise, js: true do
  before do
    @question = create :question

    set_selenium_window_size_to_large

    visit question_path
    click_on 'Get started'
  end
  scenario 'it has some questions' do
    expect(page).to have_content("Line 1: #{question}")
  end
end
```

My `.travis.yml` file went back to a simpler one:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
- 2.3.0
addons:
  postgresql: "9.4"

before_install:
- "/sbin/start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /tmp/custom_xvfb_99.pid --make-pidfile --background --exec /usr/bin/Xvfb -- :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x16"

before_script:
- cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml
- cp config/application.yml.example config/application.yml
- psql -c 'create database db_test;' -U postgres
- export DISPLAY=:99.0
- sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start

script:
- bundle exec rake db:migrate
- bundle exec rake
```

All my tests are green as expected!